# UART communication issue

Tags: avr, communication, embedded, uart, terminal

I am trying to send something from an atmega to my pc.

The setup is: Ubuntu 14.04, atmega644P-20PU, USBASP v2, TTL-to-USB pl2303

Firstly I tried to write the code in C and used this [code](http://www.appelsiini.net/2011/simple-usart-with-avr-libc)  and then this [one](https://github.com/jnk0le/Easy-AVR-USART-C-Library) and I got the same result: '�' or random characters (in minicom or screen)

Then I gave up the C and uploaded a simple Arduino program:

```
void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
   delay(500);
   Serial.write('t');
}
```

(when running arduino I put a 16MHz crystal. in other cases I used a 20Mhz one. Also setting F_CPU accordingly in the code.)

In all the cases the R(receive) LED of the pl2303 is blinking at the right moments (depending on the delay set in code).

Also I used CuteCom to view what I am getting from the serial port and instead of '�', depending on the code used I get `"\0x00\0x80\0x80"` (for Arduino code) or in other cases `"\0x80\0x00\0x80"`.

I use RX0 and TX0 (pin 14 and 15).
RX0 connected to TX of pl2303 and RX of pl2303 to TX0 of the mcu.

I also shorted RX and TX of pl2303 and tried to send data across it and I receive back what I send.

Baud rate of pl2303 is 9600

> $stty -F /dev/ttyUSB1
>
> speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
>
> min = 60; time = 1;
>
> ignbrk -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
>
> -opost -onlcr
>
> -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke

In all cases I used 8N1.

I hope I was specific enough and coherent.

(normally I try to find myself answers and solutions, but now I'm lost)

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope available that you can use to capture the signal? Also, what do you receive if you send data from the pc?

Comment: 't' looks like  `0001011101` on the line 0x80 like `0000000011` and 0x00  like `0000000001` almost certainly you have the baud rate too fast at the receiving end.

Comment: I might get to work with an oscilloscope. I'll display the results if I do. I didn't try to send from the pc to the mcu, but I will try and display the results asap.

Comment: @Jasen Great observation. But I still don't understand what else I could set. the port is at 9600, cutecom is set at 9600, the mcu is also set at 9600, with the proper crystal. I can't add a printscreen about this because I don't have enough 'reputation points'.

Comment: set cutecom to 1200 baud and see what happens.

Comment: @Jasen omg it works.

Comment: @Jasen please explain this to me

Comment: somewhere you have an 8x divider on the UART clock. I don't know enough arduino to guess where it went wrong.

Comment: @Jasen you said 1200 because I got 3 chars instead of one, and the divided 9600 with 2 ^ 3 and got 1200? I still don`t understand why this had to be done and the stuff didn't worked  at first

Comment: @Jasen Thanks * 8. You have no idea how much I struggled with this.

Comment: No, 8 beacuse all the symbols have 8 '0's at the start on the wire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

't' looks like `000101110` on the line 0x80 like `000000001` and 0x00 like `000000000` (including the start bit an ignoring the stop bit)
 almost certainly you have the baud rate too fast at the receiving end.

given that you're seeing 0 zeros and a 1 it's probably set 8 times too fast, so try 1200 baud in cutecom and look for a possible cause for the baud rate divider in the arduino to be set 8 times too high.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you have CKDIV8 fuse still programmed in fuses.

You can temporarily get rid of it by setting setting 1x prascaler in software

```
CLKPR = (1 << CLKPCE); // Enable change of CLKPS bits
CLKPR = 0x00; // Set prescaler to 1
```

Or just set correct fuses, with disabled CKDIV8 and `full swing crystal oscillator` CKSEL setting.

This is my setup for mega 328p:

[image: mega 328p full swing crystal]

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm kind of a beginner regarding avr coding. Is there a reason why I would want to use this prescaler?

Comment: The clock prescaler is usually used to make non-standard clock from internal oscillator (eg. low power&cost smbus slave at 2/4MHz).   Switching it on the fly would be really hard for begginers (eg. _delay_ms() is compiled statically for specific defined F_CPU).

Comment: got it. I wrote you and email on your email from github. I hope you still use it. I am very curious about your thoughts on it (could find a chat system here :( )